# SAP UI5 Routing and Navigation in SplitScreen Application

Tags: sapui5

I'm facing an issue with SAPUI5 SplitScreen Concept. I have one initial view on which there is a button that leads to a SplitScreen application. Until this point everything works fine.The issue is that there a two additional views (Master.view, Detail.view) that should be routed to the SplitView.

They simply aren't loaded to it and I can't solve the problem.

I have mentioned manifest.json above.

```
{
"_version": "1.12.0",
"sap.app": {
    "id": "curvy.SplitApp",
    "type": "application",
    "i18n": "i18n/i18n.properties",
    "applicationVersion": {
        "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "title": "{{appTitle}}",
    "description": "{{appDescription}}",
    "sourceTemplate": {
        "id": "ui5template.basicSAPUI5ApplicationProject",
        "version": "1.40.12"
    }
},
"sap.ui": {
    "technology": "UI5",
    "icons": {
        "icon": "",
        "favIcon": "",
        "phone": "",
        "phone@2": "",
        "tablet": "",
        "tablet@2": ""
    },
    "deviceTypes": {
        "desktop": true,
        "tablet": true,
        "phone": true
    }
},
"sap.ui5": {
    "flexEnabled": false,
    "rootView": {
        "viewName": "curvy.SplitApp.view.App",
        "type": "XML",
        "async": true,
        "id": "App"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "minUI5Version": "1.65.6",
        "libs": {
            "sap.ui.layout": {},
            "sap.ui.core": {},
            "sap.m": {}
        }
    },
    "contentDensities": {
        "compact": true,
        "cozy": true
    },
    "models": {
        "i18n": {
            "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
            "settings": {
                "bundleName": "curvy.SplitApp.i18n.i18n"
            }
        }
    },
    "resources": {
        "css": [{
            "uri": "css/style.css"
        }]
    },
    "routing": {
        "config": {
            "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
            "viewType": "XML",
            "async": true,
            "viewPath": "curvy.SplitApp.view",
            "controlAggregation": "pages",
            "controlId": "app",
            "clearControlAggregation": false
        },
        "routes": [{
            "name": "RouteApp",
            "pattern": "RouteApp",
            "target": ["TargetApp"]
        }, {
            "name": "SplitView",
            "pattern": "SplitApp",
            "view":"SplitView",
            "controlId": "App",
            "target": ["SplitView"],


                "subroutes": [{
                    "pattern": "Route_Master",
                    "name": "Master",
                    "view": "Master",
                    "targetAggregation": "masterPages",
                    "targetControl": "splitapp",
                    "target": ["Master"],

                                "subroutes": [{
                                    "pattern": "Route_Detail",
                                    "name": "Detail",
                                    "view": "Detail",
                                    "targetAggregation": "detailPages",
                                    "target": ["Detail"]
                            }]
            }]
        }],
        "targets": {
            "TargetApp": {
                "viewType": "XML",
                "transition": "slide",
                "clearControlAggregation": false,
                "viewId": "App",
                "viewName": "App"
            },
            "SplitView": {
                "viewType": "XML",
                "viewName": "SplitView"
            },
            "Master": {
                "viewType": "XML",
                "viewName": "Master",
                "controlId": "splitapp"
            },
            "Detail": {
                "viewType": "XML",
                "viewName": "Detail",
                "controlId": "splitapp"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The question is a bit too broad to answer. Have you tried following this [Fiori 2.0 tutorial](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/c4de2df385174e58a689d9847c7553bd)? There, you'll learn how to build a master-detail app with `sap.f.FlexibleColumnLayout`. The [Split-Screen layout](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/split-screen/#top), which is usually implemented with `sap.m.SplitApp`, is **deprecated**.

Comment: No , I currently haven't . Thanks a lot. I didn't know that splitApp is deprecated. I'm new to SAPUI5. I'm going to try it. Maybe it's useful for my project work in university.

Comment: subroutes are also deprecated. Try keeping it simple.

Comment: Take a look at the Master-Detail Demo App as described in [Master Detail Template](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/8ed9339f3a99418e82a02f0fb4b5d6b9). It shows the correct implementation of a FlexibleColumnLayout You can download the Source Code from [GitHub](https://github.com/SAP/openui5-masterdetail-app). If you want to dig deeper into UI5, watch the openSAP course [Evolved Web Apps with SAPUI5](https://open.sap.com/courses/ui52). The FlexibleColumnLayout is explained in week 3 units 3 and 4.